# Property [title] does not exist on this collection instance. laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am following this tutorial from 23 mins to 26 mins https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9y6Swfb8EAM&list=PL9fcHFJHtFaai-ch9icvQOU69XzsKJJtD&index=11

I am trying to pass data to view using the following code in the controller file:

```
public function show(Post $post)
{
    $post = Post::find($post);
    return view('posts.show', compact('post'));
}
```

When I try to show the code as shown below,(this is show.blade.php)

```
<h2>{{$post->title}}</h2>
<p>{{$post->body}}</p>
```

it says

```
Property [title] does not exist on this collection instance. (View: E:\xampp\htdocs\lweb2\resources\views\posts\show.blade.php)
```

Comment: pass id in find method not object. then try

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Laravel automatically resolves Eloquent models defined in routes or controller actions whose type-hinted variable names match a route segment name

You don't need to use `find()` in this case as Laravel should automatically resolve the model for you because of [Implicit model binding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#implicit-binding)

Try:

```
public function show(Post $post)
{
    return view('posts.show', compact('post'));
}
```

The reason that `find()` was causing the issue is because an Eloquent model implements the `Arrayable` interface, this will lead the `find()` method to assume you're trying to find more than one model and ultimately will return a collection.

Comment: Thnks @Ross Wilson